# changing CSS display property on the fly with jquery and apply the changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to buid a taskbar like jquery plugin. I am trying to add buttons inside a div. when i have few buttons that can fit inside parent div, then the button size can be set to default button size. When new buttons are to be added parent div start overflow then button size should be resized to fit the parent. And when they get removed again button should increase again up to their default size. Here is my code

```
    _resizeChildren: function () {

        var self = this; // this is the <div> holding the taskbar
        var children = self.element.children();
        var len = children.length;
        var toolbarWidth = parseInt(self.element.width());
        var totalMargin = parseInt(children.css('marginLeft')) + parseInt(children.css('marginRight'));


        if (toolbarWidth / (len + totalMargin) >= $('#master').outerWidth()) //#master is a <div> holding the default size
        {
            self.element.css({'display': 'block'});
            self.element.css({'tableLayout': ''});
            children.css({'display': ''});
            children.outerWidth(parseInt($('#master').outerWidth()));
        }
        else {
            self.element.css({'display': 'table'});
            self.element.css({'tableLayout': 'fixed'});
            children.css({'display': 'table-cell'});

        }
    },
```

The problem is that when I run this code, when new buttons are added up to parent div's width they are sized fine with the default size. When they start to overflow the old buttons  don't resize thus leaving very little space for new buttons which are squeezed in a very thin space to the right.

Comment: can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net link

Comment: Well, if you cant replicate, we cant either. Unfortunately we cant help much in such cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found finally a solution. That if/else block should be

```
  _resizeChildren: function () {

        var self = this; // this is the <div> holding the taskbar
        var children = self.element.children();
        var len = children.length;
        var toolbarWidth = parseInt(self.element.width());
        var totalMargin = parseInt(children.css('marginLeft')) + parseInt(children.css('marginRight'));


        if (toolbarWidth / (len + len * totalMargin) >= parseInt($('#master').outerWidth())) //#master is a <div> holding the default size
        {
            self.element.css({'display': 'block'});
            self.element.css({'tableLayout': ''});
            children.css({'display': ''});
            var maxWidth =$('#master').outerWidth();
            children.css('maxWidth', maxWidth);
        }
        else {
            self.element.css({'display': 'table'});
            self.element.css({'tableLayout': 'fixed'});
            children.css({'display': 'table-cell'});
            children.css('maxWidth', '');

        }
    },
```

Now, when I try to apply all these properties an once using only one call to .css() they start to happen all kinds of funy stuff like the taskbar resizing, buttons dissapearing etc. I haven't paid much attention to it. It works like this and i thnk it is ok.